# Android: Apply system theme to custom notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-theme

Most new Android devices now provide an ability to switch between normal theme and some kind of dark theme. I've tested it on the Android emulator, and it seems that the emulator shows white notification panels even when the system is set to a dark theme, but on Samsung's device, the notification panels also becomes dark to match the system theme.

So, my question is, is it possible to make my custom notification (`Button` on a `LinearLayout` on a `RemoteView`) to match the system theme? That is, when the system is using the normal theme, I want to show a dark caption on a bright background, and when the system is using a dark theme, I want to show a bright caption on a dark background (the same colours as the rest of the notifications), and when the user switches the theme, I want my notification panel also to change the theme.

Is that possible? Please let me know, if it is impossible or very complex.

[image: Dark notification on a dark theme]
[image: Default colours]